# Click() event not working over a button (XPATH)

Tags: java, html, xpath, automation, onclick

I'm trying to get a **Click()** event on this button (called: Add PRODUCT) but it is not working, working on a JAVA automation.

[image]

I'm getting this XPATH:

> //*[@id="order-items"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/div/button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/span

This is the FULL XPATH:

> /html/body/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JioLs.png)/main/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waYjH.png)/div/div/form/div[5]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/section[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/div/button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/span

So, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="order-items"]/div[1]/div/button[1]/span")).click();
```

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT#1:

If i click on "ADD PRODUCT" i got this XPATH:

```
//*[@id="add_products"]
```

---

EDIT #2

[image]

I got this:

> xpath: //*[@id="order-items"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)/div/button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqsP.png)

---

[image]

I got this:

> xpath: //*[@id="add_products"]

Comment: I think you're clicking on the span, instead of on the button?

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks for replying!
But that's all i got from Chrome :/. I do not understand

Comment: @ErikPragt if i click on "ADD PRODUCTS" i got this XPATH: //*[@id="add_products"]

Comment: I mean your XPath ends with /span. You could check to see what `By.xpath` returns, and if it returns at least something, try to remove the `span` from the XPath, so you click on the button instead of on the span.

Comment: @ErikPragt Erik, take a look. I have edited my question (EDIT #2). Am i doing it alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, **.click()** will only work on html active tags. second, focus directly on the button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//button[@id='add_products']").click();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Ed, take a look. I have edited my question for both buttons. Am i getting the correct XPATH in both cases?

Comment: Why the first XPATH looks like this: "xpath: //*[@id="order-items"]/div1/div/button1" (with the keyword "div") and the second one just like this: //*[@id="add_products"] ?

Comment: depends on the tools you are using, how they navigate the xpath. sometimes other html contains same IDs so its safer to focus on the parent nodes.

Comment: Is "//*[@id="order-items"]/div1/div/button1 a valid XPATH?

Comment: you have 2 buttons under this record, you can try button[2]